# What enchantments can I get for my fishing rod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The [Minecraft 1.7.2 update](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/post/65040832258/minecraft-1-7-2) included the new ability to enchant fishing rods.

> Fishing rods can be enchanted

What enchantments can my Fishing Rod receive and what do they do?

Comment: Should this be down voted like crazy, because it shows no research effort?

Comment: @jacen.garriss asking that question is irrelevant, the people who feel it should will downvote it, the ones who don't wont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the official Minecraft Wiki page on enchantments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchantments) there are two new enchantments specific to Fishing Rods, and one existing enchantment has been added:

Lure:

> Decreases average time between fish biting your hook.

Luck of the Sea

> Lowers frequency of "junk" catches by swapping them to fish.

Unbreaking

> (100/(Level+1))% chance a use reduces durability. On average, lifetime is (Level+1) times as long.

Comment: Also Unbreaking: the version notes mention that all tools can have Unbreaking now.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie thanks! I'd looked for the fishing rod icon in the other sections, must have missed it.